# How to ssh my windows server

Tags: windows, git, ssh

I already installed the git windows on my server windows 2008, I also generate keys using the git bash.

I tried to use this command `ssh-copy-id user@123.45.56.78`

```
/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: INFO: 
  attempting to log in with the new key(s), 
  to filter out any that are already installed

/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: ERROR: 
  ssh: connect to host 123.45.56.78 port 22: Connection refused
```

how can i fixed this... in my ubuntu server I have no problem on this only in windows.

Comment: Unlike most unix based OSes (not all btw) Windows doesn't ship with an ssh server. You need to tell us what ssh server you are using on your Windows server for us to be able to help you. Or do you not have an ssh server installed (and running) on your Windows server?

Comment: @slebetman , I did not install ssh server only the git for windows. I don't know what ssh server should I install for my windows server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use the same keys or to register all the keys under your main server.

Once You have the keys you will be able to connect.

---

#### `How to tell if the keys are copied successfully?`

```
user@linux ~ $ ssh-copy-id user@remote
/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: INFO: attempting to log in with the new key(s), 
    to filter out any that are already installed
/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: INFO: 1 key(s) remain to be installed 

Number of key(s) added: 1
```

In your case you see an error which means that the `ssh-copy-id` does not work so follow the next section:

---

#### `If the ssh-copy-id doesn't work?`

Simpy `cat` and copy the files manually to the server and it will work for you.

```
# Copy the output of private key
# you can also copy the public key if you need to
cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

---

Comment: can you provide me the steps if I am not using the ssh-copy-id,ssh-copy-id works only if in ubunut with ssh server

Comment: Added a full snippet for you :-)

Comment: Okay , I followed your steps. I logged in to my windows server and rightclick on the desktop select the open git bash here. and issue the comand cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa , now I see the private key...my question for this where should i paste this ?

Comment: I want to ssh my windows server using my other machine